# How to make customize xml drawable

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I want a shape like the one below, for set background tab layout.

[image]

Comment: You need a UI/UX designer to achieve this.

Comment: You can try using 9-Patch. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Comment: To simplify, you should use an image to set the background

Comment: @CườngNguyễn Yes, exactly. But I do not know how to design this background?